# inject is not defined - CodeceptJs and CucumberJs

Tags: intellij-idea, cucumber, cucumberjs, codeceptjs

It's my first time using **CodeceptJs** and I'm struggling to run my feature file as the IDE asks me to `implement steps for my scenario` but this is already done, so I feel it may be searching for them somewhere other than the specified under the codecept.conf.js file?

When I run npx codeceptjs gherkin:steps or snippets on the terminal I get this message saying `Could not include object Step Definition from ./step_definitions/steps.js from module '/Users/myUser/IdeaProjects/codeceptjs_webdriver/step_definitions/steps.js' The "from" argument must be of type string. Received undefined` .

I then move the step_definitions folder to inside features as read that this would be the default location for these and now get an `inject is not defined error`, which may be the actual cause for the issue I'm getting, but not sure what to do to fix it.

I've tried on IntelliJ Ultimate, Webstorm and VSCode but get the same on all of them.

[image]

[image]

[image]

basic.feature

```
Feature: Business rules
  In order to achieve my goals
  As a persona
  I want to be able to interact with a system

  Scenario: do something
    Given I have a defined step
```

steps.js

```
const {Given} = require('cucumber');
const {I} = inject();

Given(/^I have a defined step$/, function () {
    I.amOnPage('/');
});
```

codecept.conf.js

```
  exports.config = {
  output: './output',
  helpers: {
    WebDriver: {
      url: 'https:www.google.com',
      browser: 'chrome'
    }
  },
  include: {
    I: './steps_file.js'
  },
  mocha: {},
  bootstrap: null,
  teardown: null,
  hooks: [],
  gherkin: {
    features: './features/*.feature',
    steps: ['./step_definitions/steps.js']
  },
  plugins: {
    screenshotOnFail: {
      enabled: true
    },
    pauseOnFail: {},
    retryFailedStep: {
      enabled: true
    },
    tryTo: {
      enabled: true
    }
  },
  tests: './*_test.js',
  name: 'codeceptjs_webdriver'
}
```

package.json

```
 {
  "name": "codeceptjs_webdriver",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "codeceptjs": "^3.0.0",
    "cucumber": "^5.0.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@codeceptjs/configure": "^0.6.0"
  },
  "description": ""
}
```

IntelliJ Ultimate 2020.2

[image]

And here my [Github repo](https://github.com/francislainy/codeceptjs_webdriver)

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working now and I've come back to update it here if useful to someone else.

Was able to **keep the steps under step_definitions/steps** folder (not the one inside the features folder). To fix the non implemented issue had to install the `wdio` dependency. In order for this to take effect properly through running `npm install` both `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` had to be **deleted** to be freshly regenerated.

updated package.json

```
  {
  "name": "codeceptjs_webdriver",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "npx codeceptjs run"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {},
  "dependencies": {
    "@wdio/selenium-standalone-service": "^6.6.2",
    "codeceptjs": "^2.6.8",
    "codeceptjs-assert": "0.0.4",
    "webdriverio": "6.3.6"
  },
  "description": ""
}
```

updated codecept.conf.js

```
exports.config = {
output: './output',
  helpers: {
    WebDriver: {
      url: 'https://www.google.com',
      browser: 'chrome'
    }
  },
  include: {
    I: './steps_file.js'
  },
  mocha: {},
  bootstrap: null,
  teardown: null,
  hooks: [],
  gherkin: {
    features: './features/*.feature',
    steps: ['./step_definitions/steps.js']
  },
  plugins: {
    wdio: {
        enabled: true,
        services: ['selenium-standalone']
        // additional config for service can be passed here
    },
    screenshotOnFail: {
      enabled: true
    },
    pauseOnFail: {},
    retryFailedStep: {
      enabled: true
    },
  },
  tests: './*_test.js',
  name: 'codeceptjs_webdriver'
}
```